# Got error when trying to Fernet.Ecto.String.dump in test

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to encrypt a `String` using [`Fernet.Ecto.String.dump`](https://hexdocs.pm/fernet_ecto/Fernet.Ecto.String.html) this way...

```
defp encrypt_password(changeset) do
  case changeset do
    %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: password}} ->
      put_change(changeset, :password_hash, Fernet.Ecto.String.dump(password))
    _ ->
      changeset
  end
end
```

... in this automatically generated test (`mix phoenix.gen.json User users...`)...

```
@valid_attrs %{email: "email@domain.tld", password: "q1w2e3"}

test "creates and renders resource when data is valid", %{conn: conn} do
  conn = post conn, user_path(conn, :create), user: @valid_attrs
  body = json_response(conn, 201)
  |> IO.inspect
  assert body["data"]["id"]
  assert body["data"]["email"]
  assert body["data"]["password"]
  assert body["data"]["password_hash"]
  assert Repo.get_by(User, email: "email@domain.tld")
end
```

... and got this:

```
1) test creates and renders resource when data is valid (Api.UserControllerTest)
 test/controllers/user_controller_test.exs:32
 ** (ArgumentError) argument error
 stacktrace:
   :erlang.byte_size({:ok, "gAAAAABYzq2ofkNpJauc1vIDNrze1ORAMJXW0j0WN5bDong-cpgYYfaV75RYbX3A5yPl4fo86ctkZfszI8ePXGMejW50eRnfeg=="})
   (fernetex) lib/fernetex.ex:193: Fernet.pad/1
   (fernetex) lib/fernetex.ex:176: Fernet.encrypt/3
   (fernetex) lib/fernetex.ex:154: Fernet.generate/4
   (fernet_ecto) lib/fernet_ecto/type.ex:9: Fernet.Ecto.Type.encrypt/2
   (ecto) lib/ecto/type.ex:662: Ecto.Type.process_dumpers/3
   (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:695: Ecto.Repo.Schema.dump_field!/6
   (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:708: anonymous fn/6 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.dump_fields!/5
   (stdlib) lists.erl:1263: :lists.foldl/3
   (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:706: Ecto.Repo.Schema.dump_fields!/5
   (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:655: Ecto.Repo.Schema.dump_changes!/6
   (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:200: anonymous fn/13 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
   (api) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:16: Api.UserController.create/2
   (api) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: Api.UserController.action/2
   (api) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: Api.UserController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
   (api) lib/api/endpoint.ex:1: Api.Endpoint.instrument/4
   (api) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: Api.Router.dispatch/2
   (api) web/router.ex:1: Api.Router.do_call/2
   (api) lib/api/endpoint.ex:1: Api.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
   (api) lib/api/endpoint.ex:1: Api.Endpoint.call/2
```

When I used the command in `iex -S mix phoenix.server`, it works ok:

```
iex(15)> Fernet.Ecto.String.dump("teste")
{:ok, "gAAAAABYzq-iDjQb5i1MYY8RXbFl9ZFfDQp2wyVWqAdPJIVKgMtFap-P8AtuvsNXqrcedp5CGaJjS9M2kBD60OPOR4l_tkDO8w=="}
iex(16)>
```

If I avoid the encryption with `put_change(changeset, :password_hash, password)`, the test will pass.

This is the structure in the DB:

```
schema "users" do
  field :name, :string
  field :email, :string
  field :password, :string, virtual: true
  field :password_hash, Fernet.Ecto.String
```

According to [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/fernet_ecto/Fernet.Ecto.html), `Fernet.Ecto.String` is stored in `:binary` column in the database:

```
add :password_hash, :binary
```

Can anyone help me to figure out why this test is failing?

#### Additional (not so important/relevant) info:

- [Documentation about Fernet](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md), in case anyone wants to known.
- Why I'm trying this instead of using `comeonin`: [JWT (JSON Web Tokens) is a Bad Standard That Everyone Should Avoid - Paragon Initiative Enterprises Blog](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/03/jwt-json-web-tokens-is-bad-standard-that-everyone-should-avoid)
- I did post an [issue](https://github.com/jkakar/fernet-ecto/issues/10) on fernet_ecto github (with less details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because `Fernet.Ecto.String.dump(password)` returns a tuple of `{:ok, "hash-goes-here"}`, and you're trying to assign this tuple to a string field.

You should try this:

```
defp encrypt_password(changeset) do
  case changeset do
    %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: password}} ->
      {:ok, hash} = Fernet.Ecto.String.dump(password)
      put_change(changeset, :password_hash, hash)
    _ ->
      changeset
  end
end
```

This way, it will only be assigning the hash to the field.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Facepalm for not thinking about it first :)